# How do I load a sub-region of the worldmap in the background of a plot in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

If I plot a graph on the whole worldmap, it works:

```
scatter(a,b,c,d);
load coast
geoshow(lat, long)
```

And if I simply try to plot a sub-region of the worldmap, then too it works:

```
worldmap([21.5 25.5],[120 122.5])
load coast
geoshow(lat, long)
```

However, if I try to plot graph on a sub-region of the worldmap, it does not work:

```
scatter(a,b,c,d);
worldmap([21.5 25.5],[120 122.5])
load coast
geoshow(lat, long)
```

It simply plots the `scatterplot` without the land borders, and throws this error:

```
Error using setm>verifyAxesChildren (line 400)
There is data in an hggroup that cannot be reprojected.

Error in setm>setmaxes (line 112)
verifyAxesChildren(ax, oldstruct, varargin{:});

Error in setm (line 50)
            setmaxes(varargin{:});

Error in regionmap>setCommonMapAxesProperties (line 517)
setm(ax, ...

Error in regionmap>constructMapAxesWorld (line 486)
        setCommonMapAxesProperties(ax, ticksize, roundat);

Error in regionmap (line 120)
        h = constructMapAxes(latlim, lonlim, e);

Error in worldmap (line 122)
ax = regionmap(mfilename, varargin);

Error in taiwanHeatmap (line 38)
worldmap([21.5 25.5],[120 122.5])
```

`taiwanHeatmap.m` is my code file, where I try to define my sub-region in line 38. What could be the reason for this, and how do I overcome it? Thank you.

**EDIT**

This is the entire code of the `taiwanHeatmap.m` file on request by a comment:

```
taiwan(:,1) = (122.5-120).*rand(10000,1) + 120; 
taiwan(:,2) = (25.5-21.5).*rand(10000,1) + 21.5;

hist3(taiwan); %3D plot
[uniqueLocation, ~, n] = unique(taiwan, 'rows');

% Find number of occurrences
nHist = hist(n, unique(n));
mx = max(nHist);

% Create colors for each number of occurrence
colors = jet(mx);
colormap(colors);

% Construct a color matrix
cMatrix = colors(nHist, :);

% Create scatter plot
a = linspace(10,100,size(uniqueLocation,1));
scatter(uniqueLocation(:, 1), uniqueLocation(:, 2), a, cMatrix, 'filled');
colorbar('YTick', linspace(1/(2*mx), 1-1/(2*mx), mx), 'YTickLabel', 1:mx);

%load the worldmap
worldmap([21.5 25.5],[120 122.5])  %this line is where the error is thrown
geoshow(lat, long)
```

Comment: Can you show us code that reproduces this error? I tried it and while I cant properly show the scatter, it doesnt give error.

Comment: @AnderBiguri I have updated the question details with the complete code for your perusal.

Comment: The code does not work, undefined location. Can you show code that reproduces this error, and runs?

Comment: `location` is a dataset of about 6 GB. How can I provide it to you? Besides, it is company data. So, maybe we can create the nx2 `taiwan` matrix with random data: `taiwan(:,1)=(122.5-120).*rand(10000,1) + 120;` and `taiwan(:,2)=(25.5-21.5).*rand(10000,1) + 21.5;`

Comment: Please. Make the code so someone can copy paste and run without modifications. That does not work.

Comment: @AnderBiguri The code works, except on the penultimate line. Copy and paste the entire code before that line, and you can see the graph. In fact, that is precisely my question - why does the penultimate line, which is making a partial region of the worldmap on top of the graph, not work? If I replace the last 2 lines by `load coast` and
`geoshow(lat, long)`, it works fine and loads the entire world map. I hope you finally understood my question.

Comment: My problem is nothte one you ask. When I run the code I get `unefined lat`

Comment: Then that's a problem in the last 2 lines. Precisely my point. This does not arise in the entire world map, it only arises in sub-region of world map. So, I need a fix for that.

Comment: If lat is undefined, of course there is an error!!!! Yo need to define what to plot. If the variable does not exist, how do you plan to plot it?

Comment: My dear sir, would you please just look at the code? The `lat` is supposed to be defined internally in the penultimate line. Apparently, something goes wrong in defining it with a sub-region map in this case. That's the problem. If it was such a silly mistake, I'd have known long before, after having written all that complex code!

Answer (score 0):

That code is a bit messy, and with the little information I have about what you want to actually do I will just guess. I hope to fix the main problems of the code, and I hope to get you in the right track.

Lets go putting the code explained. The first part is good, however, unless you call figure, that `hist3` will be override by the next plot, so either you take it out or call `figure()`.

```
taiwan(:,1) = (122.5-120).*rand(100,1) + 120; 
taiwan(:,2) = (25.5-21.5).*rand(100,1) + 21.5;

figure(1)
hist3(taiwan); %3D plot
[uniqueLocation, ~, n] = unique(taiwan, 'rows');
```

the next line make no sense:. by definition, the result from unique will be unique (at least with this data) ! thus, `n` will be unique values, and the following line then will just output a `size(n)` vector of `1`.

nHist = hist(n, unique(n));

Then you take `mx = max(nHist);` This means that `mx` will be 1 with the data from here, so, again, you are creating a colormap in the next line with a single value.

This will happen for the colors, `Yticks` etc. I hope this code makes more sense in you application, else just delete it!

Now to the real problem: you want to make `scatter` and `geoshow` together.

however, this will not work. The coordinates shown in `geoshow` are not the latitude and longitude, Matlab does its own transformations in order to plot it correctly. So you can not plot `scatter` and `geoshow` together. You need to `geoshow` both. Also you are never using `hold on`, so you will never see both of them together...

Another problem you have is that `lat` and `long` donot exist. If you realise the 3 line code you wrote as an exmaple,  what generates those variables is `load coast` and you are never loading it.

In short, this code works:

```
figure()
%load the worldmap
worldmap([21.5 25.5],[120 122.5])  %this line is where the error is thrown
load coast
geoshow(lat, long)
geoshow(uniqueLocation(:, 2), uniqueLocation(:, 1),'DisplayType', 'Point','Marker','.','Color',cMatrix(1,:))
view(2)
```

[image]

Apologize if I haven't gone through all of it step by step. I am assuming big part of this code makes no sense because you tried to reduce it to a simple example and I appreciate that. If you have any questions of any of the specifics, please ask in the comments.

Comment: 1. Yes, in my application, `taiwan` is not a random matrix - it is a matrix with real data collected from server. But I wrote the code for randomized data here because one of the commenters was insisting I make the code executable by simply copy-pasting it. I thought it would generate at least a few duplicate columns, but it was not to be.
2. I did not use `load coast` in the subregion because it was loading the whole coast of the world. But let me try the last 2 lines you wrote, especially the second `geoshow` line. That might work, I guess, it makes sense. Thanks you taking the time out.

Comment: @user5346597 Hope it helps. If it helped, consider accepting and/or upvoting it.

Comment: Actually, your second `geoshow` is producing a separate figure on its own, which simply maps all the points in the matrix `taiwan` to their appropriate places. The first figure comes out separately with the same error (i.e., points are displayed on a normal XY plane, without the map having loaded in the background). What I intended the program to do was to plot these points according to their frequency of appearance (`hist3`) in different colors (`scatter`). The first program does that, except the map in the background. So, basically, how do I combine these 2 requirements in the same figure?

Comment: @user5346597 What first figure and what second figure....???? There is only one... Are you basically saying that you want different colors for the points? You need to understand that, even if I want, I can not go into your brain and see what you want. You need to explain things a bit better you I can understandd what oyu mean.

Comment: Never mind. If you're going to be sarcastic like this, I don't want your help. The 2 figures show as one was `figure(1)`, the `scatter`, and the other was `figure`, the `geoshow`. And when I wrote `figure(1)` for the `geoshow` too, it was throwing error. And I couldn't explain in more depth as I can't write more than 500 characters in the comments. But never mind, maybe I am not knowledgeable in MATLAB as I started only a month ago, but even then, that doesn't mean I merit snarky comments directed at me because of my inexperience. I am deleting this question, I will solve on my own. Good day.

Comment: @user5346597 Apologize, I wasn't being sarcastic. In MATLAB jargon, a figure is an independent window, There is no "2 figures in 1", so understand my confusion. As `geoshow` doesnt allow different colors, if you want the points to be colored differently you need to write a for loop adn go painting each of the points one by one with its correspondent color. , I understand you can not write much explanation in the comments, thats what the question part is for, to explain yourself. Hope it helps, and I apologize again because, truly , I wasnt being insulting/sarcastinc

Comment: @user5346597 Also understand that I am helping you in my free time just for the shake of helping, and I did a big effort to try to fix your code. No one is paying me for this. So please, lets keep the conversation polite both ways.